# uitableview custom cell losing its content on scrolling down the uitableview

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview

I created a `UITableView` custom cell in a nib file and separate class file for it to load the cell contents.
Right now am loading them in a `UITableView`. Currently when I am scrolling down the table view some labels are missing from the cell. When I give the same identifier name in a view controller class where am populating the `uitableview` and a `UITableView` cell nib file am facing this problem. I couldn't find out what is the exact cause behind it.

Comment: It could be because the cells are getting re-used. Pls post some code

Comment: Could you show us how you use your custom tableview cell?

Comment: write some code to get help...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/TableViewCells/TableViewCells.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007451-CH7 
Read out this apple document. Hope this will help you.